# How can you display custom build error messages in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, roslyn

I'm trying to write an extension that will give build errors when a variable does not match naming standards. I know how to use the Roslyn CTP to find variable declarations that do not follow the rules, but from there I have no clue how to mark it as an error.

Answer (score 1):

The current CTP doesn't offer a way to actually break the build, but take a look at the Code Issue Provider template to see how to get error squiggles and messages in the error list.